# hreflang links added to page source without translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

When Interface Translation module is enabled in Drupal 8, I get hreflang links to ALL languages on the site for every page view sourse, no matter if the content is translated or not.

[image]

If alternate hrefland is active on all of the pages, even untranslated ones, it creates some SEO problems.

I want to remove these links. Is any Drupal way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it refers to a Drupal Core bug that should be addressed in its issue queue at drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2521782

Answer (score 0):

These are added via a hook_page_attachments() implementation in content_translations.module. The code looks like it should not add any hrefs unless an entity translation has been created.

Some tests on my site seem to indicate that this is working correctly.  Do you have another module that is trying to add these and doing it incorrectly?

That said, you should be able to implement a hook_page_attachments() function (in something with a execution weight that runs after the content code).  In this look at the $page['#attached']['html_head_link'] array for the items to remove.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled "Alternate hreflang" module, if I uninstalled this module then these links are removed. Thanks.

Comment: But if I uninstalled this module, still we are getting hreflang for other languages for inner pages. I tried to use hook_page_attachments_alter() for our requirement but it is not overwriting the existing code. Did not understand how to remove those links.