# How do I remove unwanted hreflang links from page

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a content page in English with Japanese and Chinese translations. Even when I unpublished the translation nodes, the page source code will display the hreflang attributes to the unpublished languages in header.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://testsite.com/dining.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://testsite.com/ja/dining.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-hans" href="https://testsite.com/zh-hans/dining.html" />
```

This seems to be generated automatically. And when I run a test for SEO these language links throws 404 error because they are unpublished. How do I remove the unpublished links from the hreflang. (And it should be automatically added when I publish the translations)

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2521782

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to a Drupal Core bug that should be addressed in its issue queue at drupal.org.

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247233/hreflang-links-added-to-page-source-without-translation-d8

Comment: As a workaround try adjusting this with `hook_page_attachments_alter` or perhaps this module https://www.drupal.org/project/content_language_access might be usefull